# The sequence 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+2) + (1+1+2+4) + (1+1+2+4+8) + ..

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-complexity

I am working on a brute-force algorithm for a hard problem where the number of operations $S[n]$ seem to grow as a function of $n$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
S[1]& = 1\\
S[2]& = 1 + (1+1)\\
S[3]& = 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+2)\\
S[4]& = 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+2) + (1+1+2+4)\\
S[5]& = 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+2) + (1+1+2+4) + (1+1+2+4+8)
\end{align}
$$

Meaning, the algorithm runs $S[i]$ constant-time operations for an input containing $i$ elements.

Given the above, how would one go about deriving a formula for $S[n]$?

Comment: $$S[n]=2^n-1$$ for the first five terms. Are you sure about the sixth term? It seems to need $+16$ to match the pattern.

Comment: Sorry for that typo. My bad @InterstellarProbe.

Comment: So $S[1]=1; S[2] =3; S[3] =7; S[4]=15; S[5]=31$.... see any pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $1 + 2 + 4 + ...... + 2^k = 2^{k+1} - 1$.

So $(1+1+2+4+....... + 2^k) = 2^{k+1}$.

So $S[n] = 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+2) + (1+1+2+4) + ..... = 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ..... + 2^n = 2^{n+1} -1$.